# Add month switcher to JS calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm new to JavaScript. Found nice calendar script, but without month switch buttons. I tried a few ways to add "next" and "prev" buttons for month switching, but without any success. Need help! Here is calendar http://test.wowspace.ru/index.html

Comment: What's the homepage of that calendar script? Does it have a documentation there?

Comment: Here is calendar's homepage http://eisabainyo.net/demo/jquery.calendar-widget.php with some usage notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this I s'pose, but here's one:

You can make a hidden input for the current month offset and buttons for prev/next months and then modify the JS to accomodate these.

```
<!-- Hidden input goes in the index.html page -->
<input type="hidden" id="id_month_offset" name="month_offset" value=0 />

<!-- Put links somewhere in the index.html page -->
<a href="#" onclick="update_cal(-1); return false;">Prev</a>
<a href="#" onclick="update_cal(1); return false;">Next</a>

<!-- Add the update_cal script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
   function update_cal(n){
      var offset = $("#id_month_offset");
      offset.val(parseInt(offset.val())+n);
      $('#calendar').calendarWidget({});
   }
</script>
```

Changes to be made to the calen.js file: 
Change `var month = now.getMonth();` to  
`var month = now.getMonth() + parseInt($("#id_month_offset").val());`

Comment: Thx for answer! But this solution is not working. Here is result http://test.wowspace.ru/index2.html

Comment: @Toon, sorry for the delay in responding. I noticed that `.val()` was returning a string. You'll need to use the `parseInt()` function on the values to use them as ints. I updated my answer to show where to use them. Hope that helps